# Can I use apex-code in java outside salesforce, lets say in a servlet?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I really know very less about **apex-code** and *salesforce*. But after seeing a few demo I find their class loading per-request really nice. It will really reduce build deploy run cycle time.

So, can I use apex-code in java outside salesforce, lets say in a servlet?
Is these anything in java world close to this?

Next curiosity would be if **SOQL** and **SOSL** can run within java?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is not feasible, since the Apex compiler / interpreter is only hosted on the SFDC platform. Salesforce does not provide any offline compilers for Apex, as Apex is always supposed to be run inside/on SFDC server.
Further your SOQL queries are tightly bound to your objects - I'm not sure why would you want to do this in Java.

The only way I know of Java running SOQL queries is via web services exposed by SFDC. ( using the query/querymore methods )